# How to run a command after the previous submitted job finished

Tags: linux

as shown in the question, I want to know how to run a command after the previous submitted job finished. I know how to run Linux commands one after one sequentially.

My Linux shell is bash.

However, my case is: not all the lines in my bash script are Linux commands.
There are some jobs needed to be submitted.

```
ln -sf datafile DATA;   # link datafile to a directory named "DATA".
jsub -q DEAL ncl run.ncl; # use jsub to submit a job. jsub is a queuing system.
mv output Postdata      # move the output file "output" from run.ncl to  a directory named "Postdata".
```

The way I used to run this code is that: I put these three command lines in a bash script file named "run.sh". Then I type "./run.sh" in the terminal. 
After running this script, it failed. It popped up that the third command can not execute, because I want to move the output file in the second command to another directory. But the second command needs to take a long time to get the output.

Could you please give me some ideas about how to deal with this problem.

Comment: They look like commands to me. What's the actual problem? And what does "_but it failed_" mean? What happened? What didn't happen? What error message did you get? How did you run the script? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/549380/edit) to address these questions - ideally as if you'd answered them originally.

Comment: If its the last command that fails because the second command only _submitted_ the job (the job then runs whenever the queuing system decides to run it), then you may consider making the `mv` part of the actual job that you submit.

Comment: @Kusalananda 
Thanks for your suggestions.  
Do you mean I write the "mv" in the run.ncl file? 
Actually, I have lots of scripts like "run.ncl". I think your method does not work for me.
Are there other ways to realize that?

Comment: if jsub is some kind of job scheduler these programs often have commands to expressed the logic "do x after job y is done". You could also monitor the process and once the process terminates execute your desired command.